# Create an interactive maps from location list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, map

In SharePoint Online, I have a list with different stores location.
the idea is to work to have a  map with all our store on the SharePoint homepage.

I already found something like this but in the old classic view. (i created a new view of the list with all the information) but I can't find a way to do the same in the modern view.

Does someone have some idea to help to udnerstand how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Map View is available only in the classic experience.

There is no OOB solution or plan to integrate SharePoint lists with Bing map in modern experience for the time being.

The only solution to interact modern view with map is to use the Bing Maps web part, which is not supported to link SharePoint lists.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer